# try-catch block in Java - execution statements in catch code

Tags: java, catch-block

I have a question about the order of the execution of statements in a catch block in Java.
when I run the following class Test1 (see below), I expect to have as output first Hi!, then the result of the e.printStackTrace(); statement, and then Bye!. However, I never get this order. Please, look at the outputs, which I have pasted below.

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void calculate() {
        try {
             int h = 5/0; 
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Hi!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calculate();
    }

}
```

Output1:

```
Hi!
Bye!
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Test1.calculate(Test1.java:6)
    at Test1.main(Test1.java:15)
```

Output2:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Test1.calculate(Test1.java:6)
    at Test1.main(Test1.java:15)
Hi!
Bye!
```

I have two questions:

1.) The more important question: Why I always have Hi! and Bye! printed always one after the other, even though mye.printStackTrace() in the code is between them?

2.) Why sometimes I have the output of the statement e.printStackTrace() before Hi!, and sometimes after Bye! ? I have run the program many times and I cannot understand under what circumstances I get one or the other print.

Thank you.

I am using Java 6, and Eclipse (Ganymed).

Answer (score 19):

[`Exception.printStackTrace()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace(java.io.PrintWriter)) prints to **`System.err`** whereas "`Hi!`" and "`Bye!`" are on **`System.out`**. If you run your program on a regular console, they eventually end up on the screen, but the order may be out. If you are running the program through an IDE (e.g. [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/)), the streams will probably be color-coded so you can easily distinguish them.

Answer (score 7):

You print "Hi!" and "Bye!" to `System.out` (i.e. stdout), while the stack trace is printed to `System.err` (i.e. stderr).  The order in which they are printed is determined by when the two buffers are flushed.

Comment: Note that you can specify the stream for Throwable#printStackTrace(), e.g. e.printStackTrace(System.out)

Answer (score 2):

It could be a timing issue.  Println writes to standard out, while printStackTrace might be hooked up to standard error.  Then it's just a matter of which buffer gets flushed first.

Answer (score 1):

A1 - e.printStackTrace() prints to System.err and not System.out, so different streams, different print order.

Answer (score 0):

try adding System.out.flush() after every print (printStackTrace included).

Comment: This does not fix predicting the output order.